# How do I merge the latest commits of github project into my fork

Tags: git, github

(Sorry I'm sure this has been asked before but I cant find answer maybe using wrong terminology)

So I have a github project forked from another, my master branch is currently 5 commits ahead, 21 commits behind the master branch of the original project.

So I want any corresponding code changes in those 21 commits to be applied to my fork. Of course I don't want to lose the changes corresponding to my 5 commits either, and these changes wont be finding there way into the original project since they only make sense for my environment.

But all I seem able to do on github is create a Pull request to submit my changes to the original master, how do I do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to re-merge with them, so checkout your fork, then add them as a remote, and re-sync:

```
$ git remote add <repo_url_of_non_fork> other_guy
$ git fetch other_guy
$ git merge other_guy/master
$ git push origin <current-branch>
```

GL!

Update: a GUI way has been discovered.  Go to your fork.  There is a little message saying how far back you are.  Click "Pull request" to its right.

[image]

Then click "try switching the base" so it'll pull the direction you want.  Click "create pull request" then "merge" or something like that.  It seems to (buggishly?) list tons of commits but it'll merge as you'd like.

Then you'll have to do a git pull locally.

Comment: So theres nothing in the Github UI to do this common task !?

Comment: what is other_guy set to their github username ?

Comment: other_guy can be anything as long as it stays consistent.  Actually I did see a GUI option for that once...anyway I found a GUI way though it wasn't exactly what I remembered, but FWIW. Cheers!

Comment: when i click on pullrequest it takes me to the original project instead of leaving me on my fork, and there is no 'switching the base' option. I wonder if this is because I have admin permissions on the original project, the thing is I was given this because I kept coding fixes but Im very unsure about git itself.

Comment: That's weird yeah it doesn't give me the "switch the base" thing as of today either.  You can just do it the manual way I suppose.